# Ruby each_with_index iteration. Unsure about why else statement is needed

Tags: ruby, each

> Why do we need

```
hash[number] = index
```

in the following code?

```
nums = [11, 8, 1, 7]
target = 9

def two_sum(nums, target)
  hash = {}

  nums.each_with_index do |number, index|
    if complement = hash[target - number]
      return [complement, index]
    end
    hash[number] = index
  end
end
```

iteration does:

- nums[0] is 11:
  target - number = 2
  hash[2] doesn't exist --> we should be able to just forget about this number as number 11 at index 0 can not be part of the solution
- nums[1] is 8:
  target - number = 1
  hash[1] DOES exist and we use it's index (hash[1] = **2**) as well as the current index (hash[8] = **1**). --> this is our solution and will be returned at

```
return [complement, index]
```

the answer I keep getting on why

```
hash[number] = index
```

is needed is something on the lines of: "The line hash[number] = index assigns the index of the current number to the hash keyed by the current number. This is important because it allows the function to match the current number with a later number that, together, will add up to the target."

but since we get our result in

```
return [complement, index]
```

it seems unnecessary to me to add this line?

Comment: (1) Describing what the method should do would be helpful (for us and probably for you as well). (2) How would `hash[target - number]` ever give you anything if you don't put anything in `hash`? (3) What should happen if you don't find what you're looking for in `nums`?

Comment: There are quite a few issues with this but initially I note: *"hash[1] DOES exist"*. No it does not when you reach `nums[1]`, `nums[2]` has not been realized yet and thus `hash[1]` **does not exist**. Iteration 3 however would return `[1,2]` because `complement = hash[target - number]` becomes `hash[9-1]` and `hash[8]` does exist and returns `1` (its index) and the current index would be 2. Without `hash[number] = index` this would not be true and this method would always return the `nums` array.

Comment: true,  more details would have been good. thank you for both your help - I managed to understand where my thinking was wrong - I wrongly thought hash was populated  but we only populate it in the else statement. makes sense now. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after reading through the answer comments (thank you for these!!)

Ask was: output the index of nums of the 2 numbers that add up to the target number.

hash is initially blank and needs to be populated via the else statement in .each

- at num[0]: target - num[0] = 9-11 = -2. hash[-2] --> false, hence we move to else statement and populate hash with:  hash[11] = 0
- at num[1]: target - num[1] = 9-8 = 1. hash[1] --> false, hence we move to else statement and populate hash with:  hash[8] = 1
- at num[2]: target - num[2] = 9-1 = 8. hash[8] --> true, hence we return index of hash[8] and current index of num.each iteration = [1, 2]
- at num[3]: target - num[3] = 9-7 = 2. hash[2] --> false, hence we move to else statement and populate hash with:  hash[2] = 3